# I got this error "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same."

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

I got this error:

> Syntax Error INSERT INTO Statement

This is the correct the other one is SQL sorry

```
//Server Connection
private void ServerConnect()
{
    string ConnString;
    ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=PLAN.accdb";
    TConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString);
    TConn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("You Are Connected.");
    TConn.Close();
}

//ADD MEMOS
private void GetMemoList()
{
    string query;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    query = "SELECT MEMO_ID,DATE,TIME,MEMOS FROM TBLMEMO ORDER BY DATE ASC";
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, TConn);
    da.Fill(ds);
    this.dgv1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}

private void AddMemo(string MemoDate, string MemoTime, string Memos)
{
    TConn.Open();

    string acc;
    acc = "INSERT INTO TBLMEMO (DATE,TIME,MEMOS) VALUES (@Memodate,@MemoTime,@Memos)";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(acc, TConn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memDate", MemoDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memTime", MemoTime);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memos", Memos);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    TConn.Close();
}

private void btnAddMemos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddMemo(this.dtpDate.Value.ToShortDateString(), this.dtpTime.Value.ToShortTimeString(), this.txtInfo.Text.Trim());
    GetMemoList();
    txtInfo.Clear();
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of the `TBLMEMO` table?

Answer (score 1):

Primary key of the table may be not set to auto increment

Comment: i already do that but still the error is Systax error INSERT INTO

Answer (score 0):

The Table TBLMEMO may have more than three field in it, but you are inserting only 3 fields. Thats why you are getting this error "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same."

TRY

```
"INSERT INTO TBLMEMO(COLUMNNAME1, COLUMNNAME2, COLUMNNAME3) VALUES ('" + MemoDate + "','" + MemoTime + "','" + Memos + "')";
```

Comment: @Timart - May be in your table some column is not null, and you are not inserting that column value in your insert statement

Comment: For that you have to change your table structure, or you can insert some dummy values if you are not require that column... http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tables/design_view2007.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify your fields in query

```
acc = "INSERT INTO TBLMEMO (fld1Name, fld2Name, fld3Name) VALUES ('" + MemoDate + "','" + MemoTime + "','" + Memos + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Always specify the target columns in INSERT statements. You'll also want to use Parameters in your statement to avoid Sql Injection attacks.

```
var acc = "INSERT INTO TBLMEMO (DATE, TIME, MEMOS) VALUES (@date, @time, @memos)";
TConn.Open();
var cmd = new SqlCommand(acc, TConn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", MemoDate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("time", MemoTime);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("memos", Memos);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
TConn.Close();
```

Comment: when i used that code in the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
OleException is Syntax Error INSERT INTO statement

Comment: Can you provide the full exception details. It would also be helpful to see the CREATE TABLE statement for TBLMEMO and the full code that you executed.

Comment: Have you modified the insert to match the code I provided? The source you posted indicates no. I have modified my answer to match your column names.

Comment: but still error do yo uhave facebook plss help me ineed it in my Thesis

Comment: Knowing now that you are not running against a SQL Server database, it's important to know what database you are connecting to as it may have different syntax for an INSERT command.